# Is there a way to speed up or slow down movie clips that are on a plane?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, add-on, video

So in Blender it is quite easy to put movie clips on planes via the 'images on planes'-addon. But I couldn't find a way so change the playback speed of the individual planes. Is it even possible, or will I have to edit the videos themselves?

Comment: No, there is no way to control the playback speed of video used as texture.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens someone has found a way - it's via keyframing the frame offset.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l84oLfb0HgU